# Create new project is not working in android studio

Tags: android

I am unable to create new project on android studio.When I click create new project the console gives me this reply

```
    [  15129]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - wrong rowCount: 0 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong rowCount: 0
        at com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager.<init>(GridLayoutManager.java:85)
        at com.android.tools.idea.npw.ConfigureFormFactorStep.populateAdditionalFormFactors(ConfigureFormFactorStep.java:112)
        at com.android.tools.idea.npw.ConfigureFormFactorStep.<init>(ConfigureFormFactorStep.java:66)
        at com.android.tools.idea.npw.ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.init(ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.java:62)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:98)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:242)
        at com.android.tools.idea.npw.NewProjectWizardDynamic.addPaths(NewProjectWizardDynamic.java:84)
        at com.android.tools.idea.npw.NewProjectWizardDynamic.init(NewProjectWizardDynamic.java:75)
        at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.java:40)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:182)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:163)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:127)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:304)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
[  15138]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 1.5.1  Build #AI-141.2456560 
[  15138]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_74 
[  15138]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[  15139]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[  15139]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 
[  15139]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: WelcomeScreen.CreateNewProject
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to preference > Plugins uncheck the plugins which appear in red colour and recheck it again. Do apply Now the issue will get resolved